# Missing timezone value in POSIXct in R and local time

Tags: r, posixct

Here is my example:

```
my_time<- as.POSIXct("2020-02-01 06:20:09 UTC")
```

It creates POSIXct object and if I print its value I get

```
"2020-02-01 06:20:09 CST"
```

If I run

```
attributes(my_time)
```

I get back

```
$class
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

$tzone
[1] ""
```

Why is zone empty, it clearly displayed when I printed variable value? So I am guessing it it is attaching local time zone. Can I prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no timezone you defined. Although you think you defined the timezone, actually as.POSIXct does not read the 'UTC' indicator in your string.

Therefore, as as.POSIXct does not find your timezone.

When you print the time, POSIXct does not find any timezone in the object and assumes that you mean your timezone if no timezone is defined. Therefore you get your computer timezone when printing the object.

For example, when I run your code, I get:

```
> my_time<- as.POSIXct("2020-02-01 06:20:09 UTC")
> my_time
[1] "2020-02-01 06:20:09 CET"
```

Therefore, you should define the timezone:

```
> my_time<- as.POSIXct("2020-02-01 06:20:09", tz='UTC')
> attributes(my_time)
$class
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

$tzone
[1] "UTC"
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to prevent R from assuming my local time zone?

Comment: Sure. Define tz = CST (or whatever timezone you prefer) in your as.POSIXct function. See my second example.

Comment: Thank you again, but I would like R not to display timezone at all if it is not defined in the attribute. This way I can easily see that it is missing, otherwise, I have to check explicitly whether it is missing from attribute.